# Hiding TR when TD contains specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the below Javascript code on my PHP page, I pass the table name and a variable to the function. The "ALL" portion of the code works fine, parses through the page and flips all of the CSS style display descriptors from 'none' to '' or back.

Where I'm running into issues is the "RED" portion. It is supposed to hide all TR which contain a TD of the class "RedCell" but I cannot seem to get this part working as intended. Please help.

JAVASCRIPT

```
function expandCollapseTable(tableObj, which)
{
 if (which == 'ALL')
    {
      var rowCount = tableObj.rows.length;
      for(var row=0; row<rowCount; row++)
      {
        rowObj = tableObj.rows[row];
        rowObj.style.display = (rowObj.style.display=='none') ? '' : 'none';
      }

      return;
    }

  if (which == 'RED')
    {
      $('td.RedCell').find('td.RedCell').closest('tr').style.display =  'none';
      return;
    } 

  else
    {
      return;
    }
}
```

CSS

```
.ResultTable td.RedCell{
    background-color:#FF4747;
}
```

HTML BUTTONS AND EXAMPLE TABLE

```
<input type="button" value="Show/hide ALL" onclick="expandCollapseTable(TheTable, 'ALL')" />

<input type="button" value="Hide Red" onclick="expandCollapseTable(TheTable, 'RED')" />

<table id="TheTable" class="ResultTable" style="padding: 0px; background: #FFFFFF;" align="center">
<tr><td class="RedCell">2014-07-17 10:04</td><td>1998847</td><td>137717</td></tr>
<tr><td>2014-08-06 10:44</td><td>2009211</td><td>106345</td>
<tr><td class="RedCell">2014-07-31 16:47</td><td>2006727</td><td>138438</td>
```

So the first and third row would be hidden and second row left visible

CodePen version of code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DrKLm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of going from the child up to the parent, use the jQuery `:has` selector to filter elements based on descendents.

```
$(tableObj).find('tr:has(td.RedCell)').hide();
```

In addition, you'll probably want to hide all of the cells only if none are already hidden. If any are hidden, you'll want to show those and keep the rest visible. Here's an example of that...

```
var rows = $(tableObj).find('tr:gt(0)'); // Skips the first row
if(rows.is(':hidden')) {
    // Contains elements which are hidden
    rows.show();
} else {
    rows.hide();
}
```

The result would be:

```
function expandCollapseTable(tableObj, which) {
    var rows = $(tableObj).find('tr:gt(0)');
    if(which == 'RED') {
        // First snippet
        rows.has('td.RedCell').hide();
    } else if(which == 'ALL') {
        // Second snippet
        if(rows.is(':hidden')) {
            rows.show();
        } else {
            rows.hide();
        }
    }
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xlmcK

**Extra programming candy:**

The second snippet could be reduced to `rows[rows.is(':hidden')?'show':'hide']();`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you very much. Also followed below hint, had forgotten to add jquery src as well.

Comment: how would you do the same for first snippet? (change to show/hide instead of just hide)

Comment: `.is()` doesn't return a collection, it returns `true` or `false`, so `.length` won't return anything useful for that. And your `if` seems to be doing exactly what `.toggle()` does.

Comment: rows.has('td.YellowCell')[rows.is(':hidden')?'show':'hide']();

This does it, thank you for the help

Comment: @Barmar You're right about the `.length`; I forgot that in there when editing it from a call that filtered elements to what it is now. But the `if-else` statement doesn't do what `.toggle()` does because `.toggle()` will invert all of the rows' visibility states. Basically, `.toggle()` will "Show/Hide EACH" and my `if-else` will "Show/Hide ALL".

Comment: @James That won't work because it's checking if any row is hidden, not yellow rows. You want to set `rows = rows.has('td.YellowCell');` after you've checked this `which == 'YELLOW'`. Then you can follow the second snippet for the rest. See here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aFCyI

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvsei
Changed to this, makes it easier to put different actions and pass any class I want to hide or show.

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
$('td.RedCell', tableObj).closest('tr').hide();
```

The call to `.find()` was looking for another `td.RedCell` *inside* the first one.

Also, you can't use the `.style` property with jQuery objects, that's for DOM elements. To hide something with jQuery, use `.hide()` or `.css("display", "none")`.

And you need to restrict your searching to within the given `tableObj`.

BTW, why aren't you using jQuery for the `ALL` option? That entire loop can be replaced with:

```
$("tr", tableObj).toggle();
```

Comment: Unfortunately replacing the row with what you have given here does not work. Is there something I would need to replace elsewhere as well? Perhaps you could give the alternative in DOM format?

Comment: It should work. Can you make a jsfiddle? I'll be away for 90 minutes, I'll look at it then.

Comment: Because I am horrible with jquery at the moment. I am just barely learning to get Javascripts to work in my pages. I'm been working with pure PHP and SQL for a while now but work project demands more "fancy" elements. Could you reqrite my function from above in the jquery equivalent so I can use that as a basis for improving my project?

Comment: I made a Codepen, link above. For some reason copy paste into fiddle wasn't working

Comment: @James You need to be sure to add jQuery in JavaScript's settings.

Comment: @James I was hoping you would post what you tried when you implemented my answer, so I could see how you went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems, the .find is saying to find descendents of the td.RedCell's that are td.RedCells.
There aren't any of those...

Then, use .css to set the style.

So this:

```
$('td.RedCell').closest('tr').css('display', 'none');
```